# Crm package deployment error: The connection to the Dynamics CRM Server is unavailable

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a package in crm 2011 using visual studio 2010. When I open the solution in visual studio it connects to crm server 2011 successfully. Howerver when I am trying to deploy the package. it is giving error

The connection to the Dynamics CRM Server is unavailable.Error:

> *The connection to the Dynamics CRM Server is unavailable.*

What should I look to check this?

Comment: I have faced this error too.....In my case, it was because of slow internet connection.

Comment: When you say "package" - do you mean solution, project, plugin etc.?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this is the "generic" error during import (when there isn't a handled exception). You'll have to enable tracing and look for the failure to find the true cause.

Refer to this KB article to enable tracing:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490

I had this error once because the SDK API endpoint mismatched in a custom workflow activity.

Good luck,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to time out issues. Make sure that your VPN is stable, check that the zones are in sync and that you can connect to the organization service via e.g. URL line in your browser.